# Network Manager not working, help

Tags: network-manager

im setting a server with Ubuntu 22.04 and i have been instaling Ubuntu several times. At first, Network Manager worked great and displayed all the networks, but now nmtui doesnt show anything, and nmcli shows that everything is unmanaged or disconnected. Any ideas? By the way, I also tried a Virtual Maachine but it enda in the same way

Comment: Please [edit] with `NetworkManager --print-config ; nmcli`

Answer (score -1):

remove network-manager from your system using apt

```
sudo apt remove network-manager
```

then reinstall it.

after removing network manager you can't connect to network.
just download .deb files and install it using dpkg.  the files can be found from command:

```
sudo apt install network-manager
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Nice answer, although perhaps you should download the .deb before removing the network?

Comment: Okey so here is the thing, i tried an adapter thats native compatible with ubuntu. That apapter only lets me connect to internet on ubuntu installation setup, and the network keeps saved, so i dont need nmtui to connect. But when i plug a non compatible adapter and install the apropiate driver, nmtui works with that adapter. Some ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, i think i resolve it by myself. I just plug the adapter and I type "Sudo modprobe remove rtl88xxxu" and then "sudo modprobe rtl88xxxu". Then nmtui detects the adapter